# I want to recreate this design with storyboard and swift

Tags: swift, storyboard

I think about having a custom navigation bar. But I don't know how to create the rounded corner effect with swift and storyboard. Can you help me please ?

[image: An iOS application with a customized header]

Answer (score 0):

For rounded coreners you just need to set the `layer`s `cornerRadius`:

```swift
searchBar.layer.cornerRadius = searchBarHeight/2
```

If you want to do it on storyboards add this code to your custom class or into your extension:

```swift
extension UIView {
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: Double {
        get {
            return Double(self.layer.cornerRadius)
        }set {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(newValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to round Just top two corners

```
    yourView.layer.cornerRadius = 18
    yourView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
    yourView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Also you can use this extension

```
extension UIView {

    func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
         let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
         let mask = CAShapeLayer()
         mask.path = path.cgPath
         self.layer.mask = mask
    }

}
```

how to use

```
view.roundCorners([.topLeft,.topRight], radius: 20)
```

if you want to round all corners you can do it

```
view.roundCorners([.allCorners], radius: 20)
```